# Azure function does not accept a header with Latin character if http content is binary file

Tags: c#, azure, http-headers, azure-functions

I'm trying to send a http request to my azure function endpoint through postman. But i'm getting a Bad Request error.

```
request: POST

headers: 
Content-Type: audio/mpeg (also tried application/octet-stream)
Language: BokmålNorway

request body:
 (binary in postman, and selected MP3 file)
```

this is an azure function

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest httpRequest,
        [Blob("audios", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudBlobContainer outputContainer)
```

If i'm changing **Language** header value from **BokmålNorway** to **BokmalNorway** (changing å) everything is working as expected and returns 200 code.

The problem is only with **binary file request**. With raw, form, etc request types - Language header with "BokmålNorway" value works as expected.

Application doesn't return any error and doesn't write any log. It just returns to me a 400 error (Bad Request) every time.

By the way, application not triggering any part of my code, i can't stop it with breakpoint. I think azure function returns 400 error in its logic somewhere.

Any ideas how to fix or workaround this?

Comment: I'm using Azure Function 3.1 core project

Comment: Use the ID instead.  See : https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/iso639.html

Comment: jdweng it can be an option, but ideally i want to work with names, not language codes.Thanks

Comment: Use following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.util.httpencoder.headernamevalueencode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your response. But as i mentioned in the description Azure function is throwing an exception before triggering my function code. So i can't get this httpRequest in the code. (I'm not sure that it is exception, it just returns Bad Request)

Comment: Where are you calling RunAsync.  One of the parameters is httpRequest which already has the header(s).  So you have to encode the header before calling RunAsync.

Comment: @jdweng sorry, i'm not so familiar with functions. I tried to search in the internet what you have said but found nothing. Could you please give more details, how i can encode header before calling RunAsync? I thought that it is HttpTrigger first get your request and there is no way to get this before triggering in your function app.

Comment: Search following page for HEADERS : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration